# WSDL/SOAP support on Go?

Tags: soap, go, soap-client

Are there any packages to support *SOAP/WSDL* on Go?

Comment: Thanks for small XML/SOAP package, did the job well. Guys can find the lib here -- https://github.com/webconnex/xmlutil

Comment: I often have to use SOAP on legacy systems, and been doing it by hard coding structures in Go until last weekend. Hacked up a parser + Go code generator for WSDL that can produce usable Go code to call SOAP. Some of the APIs I use are quite extensive, generating files with over 2k LOC.
Check it out: https://github.com/fiorix/wsdl2go

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope.

SOAP sucks, but I had to implement a server of an already-defined protocol that uses SOAP, so I listened with `net/http` and decoded/encoded envelopes with `encoding/xml`. In few minutes, I already served my first envelope with Go.

Comment: Sure does, but there's an infinity of enterprise systems that only support SOAP. For those cases, we still need something useful.

Answer (score 24):

There isn't support for WSDL in Go. Support in other languages are either static or dynamic: Either structs are pre-generated from the WSDL, or it's done on the fly with hash tables.

You can, however, encode and decode SOAP requests manually. I found that the standard `encoding/xml` package to be insufficient for SOAP. There are so many quirks in different servers, and the limitations in `encoding/xml` make it difficult generate a request these servers are happy with.

For example, some servers need `xsi:type="xsd:string"` on every string tag. In order to do this properly your struct needs to look like this for `encoding/xml`:

```
type MethodCall struct {
    One XSI
    Two XSI
}

type XSI struct {
    Type string `xml:"xsi:type,attr"`
    Vaue string `xml:",chardata"`
}
```

And you construct it like this:

```
MethodCall{
    XSI{"xsd:string", "One"},
    XSI{"xsd:string", "Two"},
}
```

Which gives you:

```
<MethodCall>
    <One xsi:type="xsd:string">One</One>
    <Two xsi:type="xsd:string">Two</Two>
</MethodCall>
```

Now this might be ok. It certainly gets the job done. But what if you needed more than just a `string`? `encoding/xml` currently doesn't support `interface{}`.

As you can see this gets complicated. If you had one SOAP API to integrate, this probably wouldn't be too bad. What if you had several, each with their own quirks?

Wouldn't it be nice if you could just do this?

```
type MethodCall struct {
    One string
    Two string
}
```

Then say to `encoding/xml`: "This server want xsi types".

To solve this problem I created [github.com/webconnex/xmlutil](https://github.com/webconnex/xmlutil). It's a work in progress. It doesn't have all the features of `encoding/xml`'s encoder/decoder, but it has what is needed for SOAP.

Here's a working example:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/webconnex/xmlutil"
    "log"
    //"net/http"
)

type Envelope struct {
    Body `xml:"soap:"`
}

type Body struct {
    Msg interface{}
}

type MethodCall struct {
    One string
    Two string
}

type MethodCallResponse struct {
    Three string
}

func main() {
    x := xmlutil.NewXmlUtil()
    x.RegisterNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi")
    x.RegisterNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xsd")
    x.RegisterNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "soap")
    x.RegisterTypeMore(Envelope{}, xml.Name{"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", ""},
        []xml.Attr{
            xml.Attr{xml.Name{"xmlns", "xsi"}, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"},
            xml.Attr{xml.Name{"xmlns", "xsd"}, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"},
            xml.Attr{xml.Name{"xmlns", "soap"}, "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"},
        })
    x.RegisterTypeMore("", xml.Name{}, []xml.Attr{
        xml.Attr{xml.Name{"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "type"}, "xsd:string"},
    })

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.WriteString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`)
    buf.WriteByte('\n')
    enc := x.NewEncoder(buf)
    env := &Envelope{Body{MethodCall{
        One: "one",
        Two: "two",
    }}}
    if err := enc.Encode(env); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Print request
    bs := buf.Bytes()
    bs = bytes.Replace(bs, []byte{'>', '<'}, []byte{'>', '\n', '<'}, -1)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n\n", bs)

    /*
        // Send response, SOAP 1.2, fill in url, namespace, and action
        var r *http.Response
        if r, err = http.Post(url, "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="+namespace+"/"+action, buf); err != nil {
            return
        }
        dec := x.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    */
    // Decode response
    dec := x.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope>
        <soap:Body>
            <MethodCallResponse>
                <Three>three</Three>
            </MethodCallResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>`))
    find := []xml.Name{
        xml.Name{"", "MethodCallResponse"},
        xml.Name{"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "Fault"},
    }
    var start *xml.StartElement
    var err error
    if start, err = dec.Find(find); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if start.Name.Local == "Fault" {
        log.Fatal("Fault!") // Here you can decode a Soap Fault
    }
    var resp MethodCallResponse
    if err := dec.DecodeElement(&resp, start); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n", resp)
}
```

With the above example I use the `Find` method to get the response object, or a Fault. This isn't strictly necessary. You can also do it like this:

```
x.RegisterType(MethodCallResponse{})
...
// Decode response
dec := x.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope>
    <soap:Body>
        <MethodCallResponse>
            <Three>three</Three>
        </MethodCallResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`))
var start *xml.StartElement
var resp Envelope
if err := dec.DecodeElement(&resp, start); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n\n", resp)
```

You'll find the `Find` method useful when your data looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope>
  <soap:Body>
    <MethodResponse>
      <MethodResult>
        <diffgr:diffgram>
          <NewDataSet>
            <Table1 diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
              <Three>three</Three>
            </Table1>
          </NewDataSet>
        </diffgr:diffgram>
      </MethodResult>
    </MethodResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is a DiffGram, part of Microsoft .NET. You can use the `Find` method to get to `Table1`. The `Decode` and `DecodeElement` method also works on slices. So you can pass in a `[]MethodCallResponse` if `NewDataSet` happens to contain more than one result.

I do agree with Zippower that SOAP does suck. But unfortunately a lot of enterprises use SOAP, and you're sometimes forced to use these APIs. With the xmlutil package I hope to make it a little less painful to work with.

Comment: Go tip now supports [Marsalers](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshaler) and [Unmarshalers](http://tip.golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshaler) in encoding/xml like encoding/json already did, and this feature is expected to be in Go 1.2. This might help with handling SOAP.

Comment: Works great @luke, your small xml utility lib...js needs a get started documentation, though with a few minutes of scanning thru the script above I was able to understand how to go by things

Comment: I wrote a WSDL parser that can generate Go code to call SOAP. There's a lot of limitations in encoding/xml with regard to tags, and I put a link to that in the README. Check it out: https://github.com/fiorix/wsdl2go

Answer (score 9):

While there's still nothing in Go itself, there is [gowsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl). So far, it seems to work well enough for me to interface with several SOAP services.

I don't use the SOAP proxy it provides, which I believe doesn't support auth, but [gowsdl](https://github.com/hooklift/gowsdl) generates the structs and code I need from the WSDL to marshal requests and unmarshal responses--a big win.