# how to get data in interface{} while unmarshaling an XML in Golang?

Tags: go

I am trying to use interface{} to Marshal and UnMarshal my xml in golang. The reason is that as in calling a soap server my soap envelope, header are same but i want to pass the different soap function by passing different structs. I have made a sample code in playground(not related to soap). I am able to marshal the xml with interface{} but unable to unmarshal.

Here is link [Play Ground](http://play.golang.org/p/QrhPbEwK0e)

Please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: that's really odd. I even changed your code to use the same methods of the json encoder, the rest of the code was identical - and it worked just fine. you can see my version here - it's identical apart from the marshal/unmarshal calls http://play.golang.org/p/rX-lOz4toV

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Yes it is. Can you suggest me some other way to doing it. As i have explained in my question i need for sending soap xml(WSDL).
In which i will make a common soap Envelope struct and make a interface{} in it and for different web services i will pass there structure(Marshal/Unmarshal) during send and receive

Comment: Maybe try using http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.DecodeElement ? it will be more complicated, but seems like it might work.

Comment: here's an answer suggesting something similar, with actual code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12258671/1239701

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer i have seen that example and i will try the same with it.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I have done it with decoder also http://play.golang.org/p/DC2Pexw8Zl
But still it is not working i think there is bug in xml package

Comment: Conceptually, if `Msg` is an `interface{}` I'm not sure how `xml` "knows" to put a `Child` in there instead of some other type--it works if the type is statically `*Child` (see http://play.golang.org/p/ZoF5IumWwL). That's probably where `Decode`/`DecodeElement` would have to come in: they can peek at the XML and figure out what to create based on what kind of tag it sees.  But agree that decoding XML into a type structure not know ahead of time is going to be tricky.

Comment: Not_a_Golfer's JSON example works because the JSON decoder picks a default type like `map[string]interface{}` or the like when it has to decode into an interface{}. The xml decoder's rules are...tricky: http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal

Comment: (Something hacky that might technically work: use a `*Child` pointer like in the last Playground lik, and make `Child` contain *all* the different included in any of the reply types. That sort of shifts your whole app structure around for the sake of easier XML decoding, though, and I don't find it a satisfying solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unmarshal to an empty interface since the empty interface doesn't have any exported fields to map the xml keys/values to. If you want share your same code to "dynamically" handle the message differently, you should store it in a string or byte array (a byte array is recommended in this case). You then process the data based on your needs.

http://play.golang.org/p/sPq0ZfAcU7