# Is there a RETS package for the go language?

Tags: go, rets

I've searched for a RETS package for Go but could not find one yet. Did anyone had better luck than me finding that?

The librets c++ library has bindings for many languages but not for Go. Seems swig can't generate the binding for Go for that library. Maybe the solution is creating a native Go package?

Comment: As far as I know none exist yet. Why don't you write one.

Answer (score 1):

At this time there isn't. Go is a young language, and as such does not have a lot of niche libraries. You'll likely need to write your own.

All the information about the protocol is found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP). From what I can gather 1.x versions are based on XML (RPC?) and uses HTTP as a transport. Version 2.x uses [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) 1.2, which is also XML over an HTTP transport.

Unfortunately there isn't any SOAP libraries for Go either, so either way you'll need to use the `net/http` and `encoding/xml` packages. You'll have to make the SOAP calls reading/writing the SOAP envelopes manually.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17632770/867760) for working with SOAP in Go.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the project [go-rest](https://github.com/ungerik/go-rest). I hope this can help you.